# For Loop printing an element from an array more than once

Tags: java, arrays

For this question, I'm trying to make a code which filters out items which have already been purchased from the list. But my for loop is printing all the element from the Item List more than once while also simultaneously ignoring the if condition.

The input for my scanner is this:

> 5 apples oranges bananas peaches grapes oranges peaches DONE

The integer in the beginning is the size of my itemList array. Items which are repeated are considered as purchased. So oranges and peaches are purchased in this situation.

Here is my code:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    // 5 apples oranges bananas peaches grapes oranges peaches DONE

    int n = in.nextInt();
    String[] itemList = new String[n];
    String bought;
    String[] itemPurchased = new String[0];

    for(int i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++) {
        String item = in.next();
        itemList[i] = item;
    }
    if(in.hasNext()) {
        bought = in.nextLine();
        itemPurchased = bought.split(" ");
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < itemPurchased.length; j++) {
            if(!itemList[i].equals(itemPurchased[j])) {
                System.out.println(itemList[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the output:

> apples
> apples
> apples
> apples
> oranges
> oranges
> oranges
> bananas
> bananas
> bananas
> bananas
> peaches
> peaches
> peaches
> grapes
> grapes
> grapes
> grapes

As you can see the output repeats all the elements in my itemList array 4 times while also including the items repeated from the input. How do I make it print all the element once excluding the items that have already been purchased?

Answer (score 0):

In the loop

```
    for(int i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < itemPurchased.length; j++) {
            if(!itemList[i].equals(itemPurchased[j])) {
                System.out.println(itemList[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

You are testing whether a given element in `itemList` is also in `itemPurchased`, and then when they do *not* match, you are printing the element. This means that you are printing it out every time you *don't* match the element, e.g., if you have {"apple", "banana", "orange"}, and test for "apple", you print it once each for "banana" and "orange".

What I would recommend is to remove the duplicates from `itemPurchased`, or rather, create a third array (or better still, an `ArrayList<String>`) with the duplicates removed.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your code is worng. Just replace the last part with:

```
for(int i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++) {
    boolean alreadyBought = false;
    for(int j = 0; j < itemPurchased.length; j++) {
        if(itemList[i].equals(itemPurchased[j])) {
           alreadyBought = true;
        }
    }
    if(!alreadyBought) {
        System.out.println(itemList[i]);
    }
}
```

In your code, you check every element in `itemList` with all the elements in `itemPurchased` and in case it does not exist then print. This means if your `itemPurchased` contains `n` elements, then you will print `n` time non-bought elements